# Manage undefined value of an object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 and I want to show an image depending on the value of an object

So I have something like:

```html
<img
  v-if="results.object.value === 'test'"
  src="@/assets/images/services/img.svg"
  class="w-60"
  alt=""
/>
<img
  v-else-if="results.object.value === 'test2'"
  src="@/assets/images/services/img2.svg"
  class="w-80"
  alt=""
/>
```

So this works correctly but sometimes the results.object.value is `undefined` and it throws an error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value'
> of undefined"

So I try to add another v-if to show other image if the value is undefined:

```html
<img
  v-else-if="!results.object.value"
  src="@/assets/images/services/test3.svg"
  class="w-40"
  alt=""
/>
```

But I still get the same error. How can I manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `results.object` is possibly `undefined`, so you should verify it exists before trying to access a subproperty. You could do this easily by wrapping both `img` elements with a `<template v-if="results.object">`. And you could show a fallback `img`, using an `<img v-else>`, adjacent to this `template`:

```html
<template v-if="results.object">
  <img 
    v-if="results.object.value === 'test'"
    src="@/assets/images/services/img.svg"
    class="w-60"
    alt=""
  />
  <img
    v-else-if="results.object.value === 'test2'"
    src="@/assets/images/services/img2.svg"
    class="w-80"
    alt=""
  />
</template>

<!-- show fallback img if no `results.object` -->
<img
  v-else
  src="@/assets/images/services/test3.svg"
  class="w-80"
  alt=""
/>
```

Comment: Use `v-else` on a wrapper element (a `template`, `div`, `section`, etc.) instead of the `img`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional chaining like:

```
results?.object?.value??'default'==='test'
```

or

```
just results?.object?.value === 'test'

 <img
      v-if="results?.object?.value === 'test'"
      src="@/assets/images/services/img.svg"
      class="w-60"
      alt=""
    />

<img
      v-else-if="results?.object?.value === 'test2'"
      src="@/assets/images/services/img2.svg"
      class="w-80"
      alt=""
    />

<img
      v-else-if="!results?.object?.value"
      src="@/assets/images/services/test3.svg"
      class="w-40"
      alt=""
    />
```

Comment: But I want to show another image when the value is undefined

Comment: you still use optional chaining. check the edit

Comment: I tried but I get error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token when I use `!results?.object?.value`

Comment: try !(results && results.object && result.object.value)